# C++ pointer being freed was not allocated and show content of a vector during debug

Tags: c++, netbeans, clang

I am creating a vector of ints to store some value.
However, the code below does not seem to update the vector at all.
Error Message:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x200000001: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include "Q122.h"

void Q122::solve() {
    std::vector<int> count(200, 0);
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > > wholelist(200);
    count[0] = 0;
    std::vector<int> one;
    one.push_back(1);
    wholelist[0].push_back(one);
    int totalsum = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while(index != 199) {
        int currentstep = count[index];
        int currentpower = index+1;
        std::vector<std::vector<int> > list = wholelist[index];
        for(std::vector<int> each : list) {
            for(int number : each) {
                std::vector<int> copied(each);
                int nextindex = number + currentpower - 1;
                copied.push_back(nextindex + 1);
                if(count[nextindex] == 0) {
                    count[nextindex] = currentstep + 1;
                    wholelist[nextindex].push_back(copied);
                    continue;
                }
                if(count[nextindex] != 0 && count[nextindex] > currentstep + 1) {
                    count[nextindex] = currentstep + 1;
                    wholelist[nextindex].clear();
                    wholelist[nextindex].push_back(copied);
                    continue;
                }
                if(count[nextindex] == currentstep + 1) {
                    wholelist[nextindex].push_back(copied);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout << count[index] << std::endl;
        index++;
        
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for(int each : count)
        sum += each;
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
}
```

What does this error message mean? Btw, how to check the content of a vector? I am using clang on netbeans Mac OS.

---

#### Solved.

Problem solved: I forgot to check the bound of nextindex.

Comment: what on earth does this code do?

Comment: I am trying to solve a project euler problem(http://projecteuler.net/problem=122). Basically, I want to update the vector called "count" along the way. But this does not work out well.

Comment: You don't look like your headed in the right direction to me

Comment: You mean algorithm-wise? Yea, I am not sure about that yet. I mean code-wise, I do not understand what is wrong here. Is there something wrong when I try to update the vector? What does the error message mean? Thank you!

Comment: It means exactly what is says but I'm not sure where it's coming from since you never call delete, I would guess you have UB somewhere but I don't really want to look through the whole code, I cannot imagine why you would need a 3d vector for this I suggest you refactor your whole code

Comment: Yea, I will just start over. Thanks for your help!